# RDA file changes to different name in Environment

Tags: r

When I load my RDA file into the global environment, why does the resulting data frame change to a different name? How can I in rename it inside the function the RDA was created in?

My function is called `SaveRDAtoDisk(table)` and takes in a table name, the function reads SQL data and saves a data frame as an RDA. The problem is I know that the table name that gets input has underscores, so I assign the desired output table name to a variable:

```
name.of.table.dt <- paste0(gsub("_", ".", table), ".dt", sep = "")
```

So this should output the desired data frame name.

The function `SaveRDAtoDisk("big_table")` properly outputs an RDA called `big.table.dt.rda` but when I load the RDA, it should be loaded with the name `big.table.dt`, but it gets loaded as `name.of.table.dt` which is the variable I assign it to in the function. What is going on how do I rename it?

```
# This function takes in a table name that contains underscores
# So I call SaveRDAtoDisk("log_hunter") and it loads a log.hunter.dt.rda into the current directory

# The problem is when I load the log.hunter.dt.rda file into the environment, the data frame is called name.of.table.dt (should be log.hunter.dt)

SaveRDAtoDisk <- function(table) {

  # This line changes "log_hunter" into "log.hunter.dt.rda"
  name.of.table.dt.rda <- paste0(gsub("_", ".", table), ".dt.rda", sep = "")

  # This line changes "log_hunter" into "log.hunter.dt"
  name.of.table.dt <- paste0(gsub("_", ".", table), ".dt", sep = "")

  # This is the select statement that saves the sql query into the RDA file
  name.of.table.dt.sql = paste0("select * from ", table, sep = "")

....
  # Executes select query above
  dt1 <- dbSendQuery(con, name.of.table.dt.sql)

  # Should be "log.hunter.dt" <- fetch(dt1, rows.testing)
  name.of.table.dt <- fetch(dt1, rows.testing)

  # This properly saves the file "log.hunter.dt.rda"
  save(name.of.table.dt, file = name.of.table.dt.rda)
  dbClearResult(dt1)
}
```

So when I load the RDA into the environment, it loads a data frame called "name.of.table.dt" and not `big.table.dt` even though the RDA is properly named and the variable is assigned in the function.

Answer (score 2):

`save()` doesn't like to rename variables necessarily. You are asking it to save the `name.of.table.dt` variable so that's exactly what it's doing. If you want to save this as some other variable, you need to create a variable with that name. Here's one way. You can create a temp environment with the object with the correct name, then use save in that environment.

```
table <- "hello"   #testing
name.of.table.dt <- paste0(gsub("_", ".", table), ".dt", sep = "")
name.of.table.dt.rda <- paste0(gsub("_", ".", table), ".dt.rda", sep = "")

# store actual data in temp variable
# xx <- fetch(dt1, rows.testing)
xx <- 15    # testing

save(list=name.of.table.dt, file=name.of.table.dt.rda, 
    envir=as.environment(setNames(list(xx), name.of.table.dt)))
```

And then we can see that we can load "hello.dt"

```
exists("hello.dt")
# [1] FALSE
load(name.of.table.dt.rda)
exists("hello.dt")
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: The proper extension is .Rdata. The OPs particular problem sounds like it is best solved with saveRDS and readRDS instead, wich do allow assignment of a different name when reading because they only contain one object.